# react-native-android-wifi returning undefined

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to use the **react-native-android-wifi** package to check if Wifi is enabled on the device:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

import wifi from 'react-native-android-wifi';

export class TestComponent extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(wifi);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="Check Wifi Status"
        onPress={this.handleClick}
        color="red"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

The problem is that I receive **undefined** for **wifi** in the *handleClick* function. I followed the example usage from the package's [github](https://github.com/devstepbcn/react-native-android-wifi), but had no luck.

Comment: Only because this is a very common error on StackOverflow React Native questions, I have to ask: did you follow the instructions to completion? This is a native module so just adding the package won't work; you need to also do the linking. In addition to this, if you are using `react-react-native-app` or `Expo`, this will not work without ejecting/detaching.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have ejected the app, and also ran "react-native link" which updated the MainApplication.java and settings.gradle files. I am using Expo to run the application on my device.

Answer (score 0):

Running the code through Expo was the issue. When I run "**react-native run-android**" to run the code directly on my device it works perfectly. This is because Expo is just a wrapper and does not compile the native code.